# Visual Studio Team Services - index.html file downloaded when opening a work item

Tags: azure-devops

As of today, whenever I open a work item from the Visual Studio Team Services Board view, an index. html file gets downloaded, which has nothing to do with the work item I'm trying to open.

The contents of that file is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     // Initialize framework 
     VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformScripts: true,
        configureModuleLoader: true
     });

      // Load main entry point for extension
        VSS.require(["scripts/app"], function () {
            // Loading succeeded
            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is happening only for a few work items, but could not identify what is different for those files.

I have looked what VSS.SDK.min.js is, and it appears to be a Visual Studio Teams Service Web Extension SDK, but I have no I idea why my browser would try to download that.
This behavior reproduces in the following browsers: Chrome, Mozilla, Edge and Internet Explorer.

I'd appreciate an advice as to how to stop this from happening, but still not block downloads from other sources.

Comment: Please check in the Extensions page https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_extensions, what's the extensions have you installed?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT - It appears that I need admin rights to access the page you suggested above, I don't have that. I'm just a regular user and VSO is being managed by the company that I work for.

Comment: Can't you reach the address `https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_extensions?tab=Manage&status=active`? Even for basic users, they can also view the extension installed on this account.

Comment: Nope, I cannot. I get to the "401 - Not authorized" page. And also, it seems that today the issue is not reproducing anymore. At least not on Chrome. I have not updated my PC or browser in the meantime, so I suspect there was something yesterday specifically with VSTS.

Comment: Ok, if it happens again, you can ask the users who have permission to view the installed extensions to check if someone install an extension.

Comment: Sure, thank you for the suggestion!